# conversion of an image to grayscale using fork and join framework java

Tags: join, fork, rgb, multicore, grayscale

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;

class Multicore1 extends RecursiveAction 
{
    private int[] msource;
    private int mstart;
    private int mlength;
    private int[] mDestination;
        private int window=15;
    private BufferedImage mimage;
    public Multicore1(int[] src,int start,int length,int[] dest,BufferedImage image)
    {
        msource=src;
        mstart=start;
        mlength=length;
        mDestination=dest;
        mimage=image;
    }
    protected void computeDirectly(BufferedImage Img)
   {
       int rgb;
       int lum;
       int grayval;
       int rgbVal;  
       int x,y;
       int sliding=(window-1)/2;
       System.out.println(" mlenght valu is " + mlength);
       System.out.println(" mstart valu is " + mstart);
       float r=0; float g=0;float b=0;
       int red=0,green=0,blue=0;
```

// the image after conversion doesnot seem to be properly converted to grayscal. please look upon my code if there is any mistake
           for(x=mstart;x <(double) mstart+mlength; x++)
           {
            for( y=sliding; y <= sliding; y++)
            {

```
            int mindex = Math.min(Math.max(x+y , 0), msource.length - 1);
            rgb=msource[mindex];
            //rgbVal = msource.getRGB(x,y);
            r =  (float)((rgb & 0xff0000) >>16 ) ;
            g =  (float)((rgb & 0x00ff00)>> 8);
            b = (float)((rgb & 0x0000ff) >>0 ) ; 

    }
            lum=(int) Math.round(0.2126*r+0.7152*g+0.0722*b);
            grayval=(lum<<16)|(lum<<8)|lum;
            mDestination[x] =(grayval);
    }
    }


        protected static int sThreshold = 10000;

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (mlength < sThreshold) {
            computeDirectly(mimage);
            return;
        }

        int split = mlength / 2;

        invokeAll(new Multicore1(msource, mstart, split, mDestination,mimage),
                new Multicore1(msource, mstart + split, mlength - split, 
                mDestination,mimage));
    }

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new File("xyz.jpg"));
    int w=image.getWidth();
    int h=image.getHeight();
    BufferedImage convertedimg=grayscale(w,h,image);

    String dstName = "Gray.jpg";
    File dstFile = new File(dstName);
    ImageIO.write(convertedimg,"jpg",dstFile);
}
public static BufferedImage grayscale(int w,int h,BufferedImage image)
{
    int[] src=image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
    int[] dst=new int[src.length];
      System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println("Array size is " + src.length);
        System.out.println("Threshold is " + sThreshold);
    Multicore1 m1=new Multicore1(src,0,src.length,dst,image);
    ForkJoinPool pool=new ForkJoinPool();

    long starttime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    pool.invoke(m1);
    long endtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time took:" +(endtime-starttime));
    BufferedImage dstimage=new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    //Color c=new Color(0,0,0);
     dstimage.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, dst, 0, w);
    //dstimage.setRGB(0,0,c.getRGB());
    return dstimage;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grayval**=*(0xff000000)*|**(lum<<16)|(lum<<8)|lum;
```

You need to apply a mask before you move the bits.